# Rails - Join on Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models,`Item` and `Stock Keeping Unit`

`Stock Keeping Units` belong to `Items` and a given item can have several stock keeping units each with a status of sold or not sold.

By Definition -

- In Stock Items are items which have stock keeping units which are unsold (sold = false)
- Out of Stock Items are items which have no stock keeping units which are unsold (sold = false)

For In Stock Items here is the scope -

```
    scope :in_stock, -> {
      joins(:stock_keeping_units).distinct(:item).where('stock_keeping_units.sold = FALSE')
    }
```

How would the scope for "Out of Stock" items be? I've tried the below, but it won't get the items that have no stocks.

```
scope :out_of_stock, -> {
    joins(:stock_keeping_units).where('stock_keeping_units.sold = TRUE')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the in_stock scope:

```
 scope :out_of_stock, -> { where.not(id: in_stock.select('items.id')) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this the lambda sign does not work for me sometimes too

```
scope :out_of_stock, lambda {
    joins(:stock_keeping_units).where(:stock_keeping_units(:sold => TRUE))
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work since it won't list items that don't have stock keeping units

Comment: That's actually an error. Notice `.sold` is a method call on `:stock_keeping_units`, which is a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) instead of `joins` you get a left outer join, which gives you any items that have no stock units left.

```
scope :out_of_stock, -> {
  includes(:stock_keeping_units).where.not(stock_keeping_units: { sold: true })
}
```